# Normal Distribution and Cofffee

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For my homework I have this question:

- A coffee vending machine automatically pours different types of coffee into cups. The amount of coffee dispensed is modeled by a normal distribution with mean 120 ml and standard deviation of 8.3 ml.

  1. If cups with a capacity of 130 ml are used, what is the probability that a cup overflows?
  2. If the machine is loaded with 500 of these cups, how many of these do you expect to overflow?
  3. The data also shows that the machine successfully dispenses a cup 99% of the times it is used. Mr. Li uses the machine twice a day and pays 2 yuan each time. How many days is he likely to use the machine before he can expect to lose more than 5 yuan due to error in dispensing of the cups.

---

I have been able to solve 1 (0.114) and 2 (57 cups), but, I have problems with the third part. I know that the answer is 125 from my  textbook, but I cannot find any logical reason relating to probabilty or statistics that could let me get to that answer. Even my teacher is stumped. The best I have so far is that we know that it is only possible for him to loose more than 5 yuan, if he gets at least 3 flawed cups out of the 500. The worst case scenario would be that he gets two on the first day, and one on the next, meaning that he lost 6 yuan. The best case scenario would be that this happens on the 248th and 250th day (the last two days). And then, finding the median of 2 and 248 gives us 125. But, I confess I really don't see how this is connected to probability. Any help?

Comment: Hint: you're looking for 3 or more successes (well, failures, but still) in n attempts, where each success has a 1% chance. Use either the binomial distribution (or the normal approximation to it) to find the value of n where the probability is right around 0.5. Other hint: 3 or more successes = the opposite of 0, 1, or 2 successes (might be easier to compute)

Comment: I hope that a vending machine doesn’t normally distribute cofffee. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The wording for the third part of the question is somewhat unclear.  One way to interpret it is to ask what is the expected number of days that Mr. Li will use the machine, if he uses it twice a day every day, until he observes the third dispensing failure (and therefore lose 6 yuan, which is the first instance he loses more than 5 yuan).  Under this interpretation, we assume that the success of each purchase is an independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trial with probability of success $p = 0.99$.  Then the random number of purchases $X$ until the observation of the third failure is a **negative binomial** random variable:  $$\Pr[X = k] = \binom{k-1}{r-1} (1-p)^r p^{k-r}, \quad k = r, r+1, r+2, \ldots,$$ where $r = 3$ is the number of failures we need to observe.  It is not hard to demonstrate that $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{r}{1-p} = 300.$$  Thus the expected number of days until the third dispensing failure should be $150$.

The vagueness of the wording arises from the phrase "How many days is he **likely** to use the machine before he can **expect** to lose more than 5 yuan..." this is problematic because it seems to imply two expected values, not one:  an expected value of a *time-to-event* random variable, but also an expected value of a *loss* random variable.  This is unclear to me, so I interpreted the question in a way that chose the former:  the criterion for observing the event of interest is fixed, and we are interested in the expected value of the time to that event.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let me break my pattern of being completely unhelpful, and provide a little actual help :)

What are the chances Mr Li will get the 3rd error (thus losing over 5 yuan) on his 17th attempt? (not 17th day).

For this to happen, the 17th attempt itself must fail (1%) chance, and there must be exactly two failures in the previous 16 attempts.

There C(16,2) ways of having 2 failures (and 14 successes) in 16 attempts, which is 120.

The chance of any of these occurring is (.01)^2*(.99)^14 or roughly 0.000086874581276897830797

Thus, the total chance of the third failure occurring on the 17th attempt is:

0.01 * 120 * 0.000086874581276897830797 or 0.000104249

EDIT: OK, they are just using simple math here. With a 1% error rate, 
Li loses 2 yuan every 100 cups. That's 4 yuan every 200 cups or 5 yuan 
every 250 cups. At 2 cups per day, that's 125 days.

The "correct" way to do it:

On his 53rd attempt, what is the chance that he has NOT had 3 
failures?

Chance of 0 failures: .99^53

Chance of exactly 1 failure: Cr(53,1)*.99^52 *.01

Chance of exactly 2 failures: Cr(53,2)*.99^51 *.01^2

(where * represents real number multiplication) or 0.98384513622131652501. The chance he HAS had 3 or more failures is 
thus 1-0.98384513622131652501 or about 0.01615486377868347499

In general (Mathematica notation):

```
notyet[n_] = (99/100)^n + Binomial[n,1]*((99/100)^(n-1))*1/100 + 
Binomial[n,2]*(99/100)^(n-2)*(1/100)^2
```

Solving for this, I get n=268 for the first attempt where he is more 
than 50% likely to have had 3 failures.

So my answer would be 134, and I think your book is wrong.

Comment: Using your hint, I came up with the expression, (0.01^3)*(0.99^(x-2))*nCr(x,2) = 0.5. If everything works perfectly, the x value would signify the attempt after which the probability of the third error exceeds 0.5, but Wolfram Alpha gives me -267 as the answer (which makes no sense). I also found the maximum of the function y = (0.01^3)*(0.99^(x-2))*nCr(x,2), which gave me an x value of 200. But the probability at the 200th attempt was only 0.003.

Comment: Remember, you're looking at cumulative probability, not just the probability at a specific integer. Add the probabilities (starting with x=3) until the exceed 0.5. There's actually probably a better way of doing this, but this method will work too.

Comment: Well, my teacher tells me that using binomial distribution is probably not the right way of doing this question as the binomial implies something that is not consistent with language of the question (I don't really get that either). But, is there another way to solve this question?

Comment: Using a similar method, I got the same result---134 days.  (The number of days required to increase the probability of getting a 6 yuan or larger loss above 50%).  I am also thinking your book is wrong.